# wx.Treectrl item look up table

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to create a look up table to connect `wxTreeItem` to objects. Upon selecting or double clicking on the item an action should be taken on this object.
Mysteriously, I found that item instance returned after `AppendItem` is either a copy of the real item appended to the tree or `self.tree.GetSelection()` and `event.GetItem()` return a copy of the item in question.

```
import wx

class RandomObj(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class TreeExample(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Tree Example', size=(200, 130))
        self.tree = wx.TreeCtrl(self, size=(200, 100))

        root = self.tree.AddRoot('root')
        self.itemLUT = {}
        for obj in [RandomObj('item1'), RandomObj('item2'), RandomObj('item3')]:
            item = self.tree.AppendItem(root, obj.name)
            print item
            self.itemLUT[id(item)] = obj
            self.itemLUT[id(obj)] = item

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.OnActivated, self.tree)
        self.tree.Expand(root)

    def OnActivated(self, event):
        item = event.GetItem()
        print 'Double clicked on', self.tree.GetItemText(item)
        print id(item) in self.itemLUT.keys()
        print self.tree.GetSelection()
        print item

app = wx.PySimpleApp(None)
TreeExample().Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Any suggestions? is there any proper way to connect and access an object upon an action (mouse or keyboard) on an tree item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a good way to do it is

```
item = self.tree.AppendItem(root, obj.name)
self.tree.SetItemData(item, wx.TreeItemData(obj))
```

and in the event method

```
def OnActivated(self, event):
    item = event.GetItem()
    itemObject = self.tree.GetItemData(item).GetData()
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way is just to put your data into the item with `SetItemData`:

```
item = self.tree.AppendItem(root, obj.name)
self.tree.SetItemData(item,obj)
```

Then later, you can use `GetItemData` to extract the data back out of the item. You can put just about anything in there.